# Angular 4 Back and Next buttons

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning right now Angular 4 because I have to build a project with it. In one task I have to implement a Back and Next buttons functionality.

These buttons are only on 4 pages(step1 to step4), pages that are in the sidebar.
I get to step one from a search result. The result from searches is step1 page. So after I search a companies, I select the one that I want and click next. The back, next buttons are in the bottom of each these 4 steps pages.  So I click next each step until step 4 or I can go back, with back button.
On the sidebar, each step when is active has a diff color.

Each step page is a individual component. Sidebar, where I have the links for these steps, is another component. The buttons is another component, included in the bottom of each 4 steps page.

Because I'm new to angular 4, my question is how to do this flow: click next from step 1 to step 4(or back) and the sidebar component to be informed too about this change.

Because of the security, believe I can't put any code. I sign too many papers in this direction. Please I need some ideas, if someone can give me a hand.

Comment: I need Ideas not code, as I said. Please stop give me -. Who give - has no idea how to work in a project with a lot of security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project looks like a `step wizard` component, so maybe you can take a look to this project : https://github.com/maiyaporn/angular2-wizard